# multiple clients connecting to a server using fifos in c language

Tags: struct, while-loop, server, client, fifo

I have a small issue here that I need help with. I have a server that has to accept several clients at the same time, and it has to process some information before sending back the information to the client. It has to send the information through a private fifo (which has to be created in the server for the client) to each client. I know it has to do something with a while loop and the server has to end when there are no more clients connected.

So far I have gotten 1 client connecting to the server. The server finishes right when there is nothing else to process. I know this could be done with a socket but they want specifically fifos and a while loop. Thanks for any help, here is my code that I need to modify:

client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


// creating the struct for the program
struct probsiz{
   int seg1 [1]; //segment 1 size
   int seg2 [1]; //segment 2 size
   int seg3 [1]; //segment 3 size
   int segsum [7]; //sum for all the segments
   int leftov [1]; //memory leftovers

} ;

struct probseg {     

   char segment[64]; //segments
};


main (void)
{
  struct probsiz numbs; //defining the structures
  struct probseg names; 

  int fda;  // to write to character server
  int fdb;  // to read response from character server


  memset(numbs.seg1, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the first segment
  memset(numbs.seg2, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the second segment
  memset(numbs.seg3, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the third segment
  memset(numbs.segsum, 0, 7);// setting up memory for the sum of all segments
  memset(numbs.leftov, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the first segment
  memset(names.segment, 0, 64);// setting up memory for the segments


  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

  if((fdb=open("FIFO2", O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to read");

  //reading the requested memory and segment name from the user
  printf("Client: Please enter requested memory 1: ");
  scanf("%d", &numbs.seg1[0]);
  while (numbs.seg1 <=0){
      printf("Client: please enter a valid request: ");
      scanf("%d", &numbs.seg1[0]);
  }
  printf("Client: Please enter segment 1 name: ");
  scanf("%s", &names.segment[0]);


  printf("Client: Please enter requested memory 2: ");
  scanf("%d", &numbs.seg2[0]);
  while (numbs.seg1 <=0){
      printf("Client: please enter a valid request: ");
      scanf("%d", &numbs.seg2[0]);
  }
  printf("Client: Please enter segment 2 name: ");
  scanf("%s", &names.segment[1]);


  printf("Client: Please enter requested memory 3: ");
  scanf("%d", &numbs.seg3[0]);
  while (numbs.seg3 <=0){
      printf("Client: please enter a valid request: ");
      scanf("%d", &numbs.seg3[0]);
  }
  printf("Client: Please enter segment 3 name: ");
  scanf("%s", &names.segment[2]);

  //send and write into the fifos

  printf("\nClient: Got the sizes sent now waiting for server's response\n");

 write(fda, &numbs, sizeof(struct probsiz));
 write(fda, &names, sizeof(struct probseg));


  //read from the fifos
 read(fdb, &numbs, sizeof(struct probsiz));

 if (numbs.leftov[0] >=0) {

     printf("\nClient: address for segment 1 is: %d - %d", numbs.segsum[0], numbs.segsum[1]);
     printf("\nClient: address for segment 2 is: %d - %d", numbs.segsum[2], numbs.segsum[3]);
     printf("\nClient: address for segment 3 is: %d - %d", numbs.segsum[4], numbs.segsum[5]);
     printf("\nClient: leftover memory is: %d", numbs.leftov[0]);
     printf("\nall done!");
 }
 else
 {
     printf("\nClient: segment size is over the capacity, please try again");
     printf("\nall done!\n");

 }

  //this closes the fifos
  close(fda);
  close(fdb);


  printf("\nall done!\n");

}
```

server:

```
// creating the struct for the program
struct probsiz{
   int seg1 [1]; //segment 1 size
   int seg2 [1]; //segment 2 size
   int seg3 [1]; //segment 3 size
   int segsum [7]; //sum for all the segments
   int leftov [1]; //memory leftovers

} ;

struct probseg {     

   char segment[64]; //for the segments
};

main (void)
{
  struct probsiz numbs; //  structure definitions
  struct probseg names;


  int fda;  // to read from client char
  int fdb;  // to write to client char
  int finish;   // lets me know that client is done
  int i;    // because C needs this defined as int
  int m=2000; //total memory units
  int mtot;  //memory total from the sum of all the segments

  //setting up the memory 

  memset(numbs.seg1, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the first segment
  memset(numbs.seg2, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the second segment
  memset(numbs.seg3, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the third segment
  memset(numbs.segsum, 0, 7);// setting up memory for the sum of all segments
  memset(numbs.leftov, 0, 1); //setting up memory for the first segment
  memset(names.segment, 0, 64);// setting up memory for the segments


  /* Create the fifos and open them  */
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO1",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create FIFO1");
    exit(-1);
    }
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO2",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create FIFO2");
    exit(-1);
    }
  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");
  if((fdb=open("FIFO2", O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to read");



  read(fda, &numbs, sizeof(struct probsiz)); //read the sizes
  finish=read(fda, &names, sizeof(struct probseg)); //read the segments

  //printing out the characters on the server side to validate the data in

  strcpy(names.segment, names.segment);
  mtot=numbs.seg1[0]+numbs.seg2[0]+numbs.seg3[0];
  numbs.leftov[0]=m-mtot;

  //printf("\nServer: just got segment 1: %s", names.segment[0]);
  printf("\nServer: just got segment 1 size: %d", numbs.seg1[0]);

  //printf("\nServer: just got segment 2: %s", names.segment[1]);
  printf("\nServer: just got segment 2 size: %d", numbs.seg2[0]);

  //printf("\nServer: just got segment 3: %s", names.segment[2]);
  printf("\nServer: just got segment 3 size: %d", numbs.seg3[0]);


  //calculation of memory addresses
  numbs.segsum[0]=0;
  numbs.segsum[1]= numbs.seg1[0]-1;
  numbs.segsum[2]= numbs.seg1[0];
  numbs.segsum[3]= numbs.segsum[2]+numbs.seg2[0]-1;
  numbs.segsum[4]= numbs.segsum[3]+1;
  numbs.segsum[5]= numbs.segsum[4]+numbs.seg3[0];
  numbs.segsum[6]=0;


  write(fdb, &numbs, sizeof(struct probsiz));

  if (numbs.leftov[0] >=0) {

     printf("\nClient: address for segment 1 is: %d - %d", numbs.segsum[0], numbs.segsum[1]);
     printf("\nClient: address for segment 2 is: %d - %d", numbs.segsum[2], numbs.segsum[3]);
     printf("\nClient: address for segment 3 is: %d - %d", numbs.segsum[4], numbs.segsum[5]);
     printf("\nClient: leftover memory is: %d", numbs.leftov[0]);
     printf("\nall done!");
 }
 if (numbs.leftov[0]<=0)
 {
     printf("\nClient: segment size is over the capacity, please try again");
     printf("\nall done!\n");

 }

  if(finish == 1)
    printf("\nServer: This says I am ready to close ");
  close(fda);
  close(fdb);
  unlink("FIFO1");
  unlink("FIFO2");

}
```

Comment: Please, try to simplify your code examples. It's difficult to focus on the problem you describe with so much code bloat.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind for the future. with that being said, any suggestion for the problem in question?